# If $x$ is rational and $\sin(x)$ is irrational, then is $\cos(x)$ irrational?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am wondering if the following implication is true. I know it is not true if $x$ is irrational, as clearly $x =\pi/3$ is a counterexample.

$$\text{$x$ is rational and $\sin(x)$ is irrational} \implies \cos(x) \text{ is irrational}$$

I know irrationals are not closed under multiplication or addition. However, this *seems* true.

If there is an obvious counterexample I am missing, I apologize.

Comment: $x=\pi/3$, maybe?

Comment: Thanks so much! I am only looking to consider rational $x$ values. I don't believe $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is rational...

Comment: How is $\frac\pi2$ a counterexample?  $\sin(\frac\pi2)$ is rational

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I suspect that's a typo for $\pi\over 3$.

Comment: Yes it was! Nice catch. Just edited it.

Comment: If $x$ is non-zero and rational, then $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ are transcendental  and hence irrational by [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: Thanks @achillehui ! If you post this as an answer I will confirm it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A form of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem states that if $a_1,...,a_n$ are algebraic numbers and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are *distinct* algebraic numbers, then the only solution to :
$$
a_1e^{\alpha_1} + ... + a_n e^{\alpha_n} = 0
$$

is $a_i = 0$ for all $i$.

---

Suppose that for some $x$ non-zero rational (in fact, algebraic), we have $\sin x$ is rational. In particular, $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{ix}}{2i}$, so we get $e^{ix} - e^{-ix} = 2iq$ for some rational $q$. Rearranging gives us :
$$
(1)e^{ix} + (-1)e^{-ix} + (-2iq)e^0 = 0
$$

If $x$ is non-zero , then the above contradicts the LW theorem because $ix,-ix$ and $0$ are distinct algebraic numbers. This shows that $\sin x$ is in fact irrational. But we can say more : see if you can prove that $\sin x$ is *transcendental* using this fact.

---

From here, a similar trick can be used to show that if $x$ is non-zero algebraic then $\cos x$ is irrational. Thus your implication is clear since both sides of it are always true unless $x=0$ in which case both sides are false, so the implication holds always.